# How do I open cakephp's index.php through MAMP?

Tags: php, cakephp, mamp

I'm very new to web designing and I recently installed MAMP and Cakephp. (configured for MAMP as per many tutorials online). I'm learning cake through the blog tutorial. I want to know how to access cake's index.php file on the web browser. The cake bake console runs fine through the command line. But, all of cakephp's files are stored in /Users/username/Sites/cake (Tutorial asked me to place the file there) while MAMP's document root is /Applications/MAMP/htdocs. 
Now, I'm not sure how to proceed with this blog tutorial and access cakephp files through the web browser, being hosted by the localhost on MAMP. 
I'm really confused and could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

Move all your files to `htdocs`.

The cake core should go into `htdocs\lib\Cake`.
Your app files should be in `htdocs\app`.

So your `htdocs` should look like this:

```
htdocs\
    app\
    lib\
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

more info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html